# Pass remote Computer name variable from batch file to hta and print out the value in a pop up or html window

Tags: javascript, batch-file, variables, vbscript, hta

I'm trying to pass a variable from a batch file to an hta which needs to be displayed in a pop up window of some sort - either html or vbscript.

The computer name is looped through a batch file which opens individual instances so all I would need to pass is the variable "%1".

What I'm needing is a way to either bring that variable over to VBscript or Javascript, then print via html.

Comment: Hello, why was this closed? It's probably not the best quality question but it is straightforward enough and contains all necessary information. Op was probably unfamiliar with term "command line" or didn't realize to google it in this context, or didn't understand that it is what they needed.

Comment: Here's the quoted reason: We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations.

Yes, I am new to HTA, I've done html, and some vbscript manipulation, but javascript is new to me, and I'm unfamiliar with the best practices. Originally, I asked about an HTA based countdown timer, but an individual with 32k rep asked me why I needed it, and I pointed out why is irrelevant to my question. Overall, it would be a jumping point to understanding and learning.

Comment: I've made posting questions to this site my absolute last resort due to how people get treated here.

Comment: Ok I don't see anything that suggests that you are asking for software or book recommendations. Perhaps the moderator who closed this was unfamiliar with what HTA is? I've looked at your question about timer and it was somewhat vague - you included a lot of irrelevant information that seemed to throw people off. You could perhaps restructure that question to be more straightforward like this one and only include relevalant working pieces of code. Also please read and understand the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Because I think I probably answered your question enough (you can google it further - search for `hta commandline` or something) I think trying to dispute its closure is probably a waste of time - instead if this didn't help you enough ask additional questions, hopefully a little better. Explain what exactly you are trying to accomlish, what you tried and how it failed, provide minimal *relevant* working example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CommandLine` property of your HTA appliction object (i.e. its `ID`).

It contains full verbatim command line with your HTA filename (and possibly path) followed by arguments you supplied when running the HTA

This means you can pass arguments through the command line of your HTA, for example:

```
start "" "c:\your-path\your-app.hta" "%~1"
```

`"%~1"` ensures that the first parameter is always in double-quotes irregardless original %1 having them or not. This works only in an actual batch file.

How to extract first commandline argument:

- Check if first character of `CommandLine` is `"`

  - If so - find next `"`
  - Otherwise - find next space (`" "`) or tab (`"\t"`)
- Skip any consecutive spaces and/or TABs after position you found
- Again check if first remaining character is `"`

  - If so - also find next `"` - your argument is between the double-quotes
  - Otherwise - your argument is between current position and first of: `" "`, "\t"` or end-of-string

All of this can be done manually or with the help of regular expressions

Since you are the one who runs the HTA you could in theory exclude code that runs in absence of double-quotes by always including them on the command line, although this is not recommended

For more info see [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-pass-command-line-variables-to-an-hta-when-it-starts/) article about passing parameters to HTA, it also includes example VBS code